# How to connect to private network without using ports

Tags: networking, ssh, private-network

So i live in a student dormitory and i have access to the internet with 1 cable.
This cable is plugged into my router (Netgear R6200) and i have a few PC's running on that router with cables.

Now i bought my Raspberry Pi 2 model B and started setting up a few servers.
I want to connect to my Pi from the outside (from college).
I cannot open ANY ports or have administrator privileges for the network, i do however have the liberty to set up anything i want.
Is there any way possible to get a connection (be it with SSH or FTP) established from my college network, to my Pi in my own private network.

I have quite a background on networks and PC hardware, so please dont hold back on any "scary" terms or schematics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can use teamviewer VPN with 2 accounts to link windows computers together from different locations without any ports.
I there some kind of software like this for Linux?
I have been googling like a madman all day :)

Comment: I am using Raspbian on my Pi, and windows 7 on all my windows machines.

Comment: Welcome at SU. Please improve your question via [edit] button rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your network does not allow incoming connections (i.e. there is a firewall you don't control which is blocking all incoming ports), then you will have to use an intermediate server (which is what teamviewer uses).

If you have SSH access to a remote computer you can set up an [ssh reverse tunnel](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh%20reverse%20tunnel) to make your local services available remotely.

Otherwise, if you don't mind the potential security risks, there are several online services which provide similar functionality:

- [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/)
- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)